# Audit everything coming from an ip adress in an Oracle database

Tags: oracle, audit

I need to audit all activity coming from a specific ip adress. Whats the best method to do this in an Oracle Database 19c?

Answer (score 2):

With Unified Auditing.

[Oracle Database Auditing](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/security/db-auditing.html)

> Oracle Database **Unified Auditing** enables selective and effective
> auditing inside the Oracle database using policies and conditions. The
> new policy based syntax simplifies management of auditing within the
> database and provides the ability to accelerate auditing based on
> conditions. For example, audit policies can be configured to audit
> based on **specific IP addresses**, programs, time periods, or connection
> types such as proxy authentication.

Example:

```
CREATE AUDIT POLICY mypolicy
ACTIONS ...
WHEN 'SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'', ''IP_ADDRESS'') = ''1.2.3.4'''
EVALUATE PER SESSION;
```